# Extend an Interface which can be defined by the user

Tags: typescript

I want to extend an interface which could be potentially defined by a user. To make it clear I'll try to give and example:

I have a state which is defined by the following interface:

```
interface State {
  keyA: {},
  keyB: {},
  ...
}
```

State can be anything like Store, Books, Apples... anything.

Now I want to enhance this interface with new properties like so:

```
interface EnhancedState extends State {
  enahncedProp: {},
  ...
}
```

The problem is that I don't know what is State so I would do something like:

```
interface EnhancedState<T> extends T {
  enahncedProp: {},
  ...
}
```

But TypeScript doesn't allow that. How can I achieve this behaviour?

**EDIT**

---

An example in React and Redux (Redux Toolkit):

In Redux Toolkit I can create a state slice which defines some data to hold in state and I would do something like this:

```
slice = createSlice({
  ...options,
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
     ...
  }
})
```

For some slices I want to provide enchaned features and that means I would have to provide the same options to each slice which is created that way. Let's say a slice which handles the state of http requests (for example).

I created a so called *Higher Order Function* which is nothing more than a wrapper function to the original function like so:

```
createSliceWithRequests = <T>(options) => {
  createSlice({
    ...options,
    initialState: {
       ...options.initialState,
       enhancedProps: {}
    } // <-- this is of type EnhancedState<t> extends T
    reducers: {
      reducerWhichHandleRequests,
      ...options.reducers
    }
  })
}
```

Now I want that this function returns an `EnhancedState` which has the initial state the user gave in the options plus the properties of the requests features.

Comment: What would be the concrete usage of `EnhancedState`? I'm not sure to understand why you need it to be generic. Maybe you share some examples of the usage you expect

Comment: Who defined `Store, Books, Apples`? It is a bit unclear to me.

Comment: I added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible at the moment to do something like this.

An alternative would be to use a type, but it will not have the inheritance feature.

```
type EnhancedState<T> = T & {
  ...
}
```

You can check out this [GitHub thread](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2225) for more information.

Comment: I see. This is the feature I'm looking for.